# Игра угадай число для бота / Telegram, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа, telebot

У меня есть главный файл бота `main.py`, я импортировал файл `games.py` в `main.py` и собираюсь вызывать игру через функцию, но мне надо чтоб весь текст который в коде выводил бот сообщением, и на текст который ему отправишь он отвечал - угадал число, меньше или больше оно.

Я новичок и код не работает, пишет ошибку при запуске `TypeError` мол я в условной конструкции сравниваю `str` и `int`, помогите исправить чтоб код работал, можете доработать чтоб если пользователь вводил текст бот отвечал что это не число.

**Вот код игры:**

```
import random

def random_guesses(message):
guesses_made = 0

name = str(message.chat.first_name) + " " + str(message.chat.last_name)

number = random.randint(1, 30)
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '{0}, я загадал число между 1 и 30. Сможешь угадать?'.format(name))

while guesses_made < 6:

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите число")
    guess = int(message.text)

    guesses_made += 1

    if guess < number:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Твое число меньше того, что я загадал.')

    if guess > number:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Твое число больше загаданного мной.')

    if guess == number:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ух ты, {0}! Ты угадал мое число, использовав {1} попыток!'.format(name, guesses_made))
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'А вот и не угадал! Я загадал число {0}'.format(number))
```

**А вот код вызова этой функции в файле main.py:**

```
import telebot
import config
import conf_games
import time

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_message(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'привет': 
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'хай')
    elif  message.text.lower() == 'угадай число': 
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, conf_games.random_guesses(message))
```

Comment: не всегда text можно преобразовать в Int
например, если в сообщении точка или буква

Comment: Можно как то доработать код что бы он хотя бы работал?

Comment: проще уже с 0 написать

Comment: Что именно можно по точнее?

Comment: Проверяйте ввод с помощью функции `isdigit()` , если `True`, приводите к `int` и обрабатываете, если `False`, то выводите сообщение о некорректном вводе

Comment: А как это можно впихнуть в код?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работает код для игры в угадай число для бота в тг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1181807/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b3)

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так:

```
 while guesses_made < 6:
    
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите число")
        
        if message.text.isdigit():
            guess = int(message.text) 
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Неверный ввод. Введите число")
```

**UPDATE**. Измените проверку. Проверяйте через исключение это будет правильнее:

```
while guesses_made < 6:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите число")
    try:
        guess = int(message.text)
    except ValueError:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Неверный ввод. Введите число")
    else:
        guesses_made += 1
        if guess < number:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Твое число меньше того, что я загадал.')

        if guess > number:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Твое число больше загаданного мной.')

        if guess == number:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         'Ух ты, {0}! Ты угадал мое число, использовав {1} попыток!'.format(name, guesses_made))
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'А вот и не угадал! Я загадал число {0}'.format(number))
```

Comment: Я добавил, все заработало, но теперь другая ошибка "unboundlocalerror local variable "guess" referenced before assignment". Как исправить?

Comment: Просто вставьте `guess = 0` после `guesses_made = 0` в начале тела функции

Comment: Не выходит, после ввода "Угадай число" бот начинает писать вот такую штуку https://ibb.co/rGqLb2c, я даже не успеваю ничего ответить