# Не работает код для игры в угадай число для бота в тг

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Никак не могу написать код для игры в угадай число для бота, код пишу в отдельном файле(не главном), чтобы потом вызвать его функцией, вот код игры:

```
import random
import time


def random_guesses(message,bot):
# число попыток угадать
    guesses_made = 0
    guess = 0

# получаем имя пользователя из консольного ввода
    name = str(message.chat.first_name)

# получаем случайное число в диапазоне от 1 до 30
    number = random.randint(1, 30)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '{0}, я загадал число между 1 и 30. Сможешь угадать?'.format(name))
    time.sleep(1)

# пока пользователь не превысил число разрешенных попыток - 6
    while guesses_made < 6:
        
    
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введи число")
        
        try:
            guess = int(message.text)
        except ValueError:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Неверный ввод. Введите число")

        
    # увеличиваем счетчик числа попыток
        guesses_made += 1

        if guess < number:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Твое число меньше того, что я загадал.')

        elif guess > number:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Твое число больше загаданного мной.')

    if guess == number:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ух ты, {0}! Ты угадал мое число, использовав {1} попыток!'.format(name, guesses_made))
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'А вот и не угадал! Я загадал число {0}'.format(number))
```

Вызов функции идёт с главного файла кодом:

```
if message.text.lower() == "Угадай число":
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, conf_games.random_guesses(message, bot))
```

Когда пишу боту "Угадай число" игра запускается, но бот пишет вот это, я даже ответить не успеваю, он строчит без остановки: https://ibb.co/rGqLb2c В консоли вот это: https://ibb.co/pJLp2SF Помогите доработать что бы игра работала, заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Вот это -  ``if message.text.lower() == "Угадай число"`` - никогде не будет True.

Comment: Тогда как можно сделать игру в угадай число если это никогда не будет True

Comment: В какой строчке вообще производится ввод числа?

Comment: посмотреть внимательно на код и сообразить, почему там не может быть true. Подсказка: ``lower()`` и "У".

Comment: Да это я исправил давно, простите за опечатку в вопросе

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1182016/234134

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работает код игры "Угадай число" для бота в ТГ Python pytelegrambotapi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1181713/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%a3%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%a2%d0%93-python-pytelegrambotapi)

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import time
import pytelegrambotapi


def random_guesses(message,bot):
    # число попыток угадать
    guesses_made = 0
    guess = 0

    # получаем имя пользователя из консольного ввода
    name = str(message.chat.first_name)

    # получаем случайное число в диапазоне от 1 до 30
    number = random.randint(1, 30)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '{0}, я загадал число между 1 и 30. Сможешь угадать?'.format(name))
    time.sleep(1)

    # пока пользователь не превысил число разрешенных попыток - 6
        
    
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введи число")
        
    try:
        guess = int(message.text)
    except ValueError:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Неверный ввод. Введите число")

        
    # увеличиваем счетчик числа попыток
    guesses_made += 1

    if guess < number:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Твое число меньше того, что я загадал.')

    if guess > number:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Твое число больше загаданного мной.')

    if guess == number:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ух ты, {0}! Ты угадал мое число, использовав {1} попыток!'.format(name, guesses_made))
        break
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'А вот и не угадал! Я загадал число {0}'.format(number))
        break
```

Comment: я забыл в функции добавить табуляцию. Надеюсь ты сделаешь это сам)

Comment: подкорректировать ответ и добавить табуляцию, а так же хотя бы краткие объяснения, можно нажав на кнопку "править" под ответом.

Comment: Ошибку выдаёт, https://ibb.co/n8VCNWq, отступы сделал

Comment: Убери break если ты убрал цикл

Comment: Убрал break, все равно не работает ничего